# Convolution and Characters

Tags: representation-theory, lie-algebras

I am confused about the purpose of the Formal Character, character functions, and the convolution in representation theory of Lie algebras. Is the Character function different than just the Character? Can someone either explain what they are and their purpose, or direct me somewhere that can?

Thank you for your help and hope this is clear.

Comment: Be more precise. What convolution are you talking about?

Comment: The convolution is from Humphreys' intro to Lie Algebras and Rep.theory. The book doesn't give it a name. The section talks  about "F-valued" functions on the space of weights. It says that this is the space of functions denoted $\mathfrak {X} $ whose "support" is included in a finite union of sets of the form         $ \lambda - \sum {k_\alpha \alpha} $. Where k and $\alpha $ are positive and alpha is a root. ( basically quoted from the book). This space is an algebra closed under the convolution and contains the formal character of any standard cyclic module. (Also somewhat quoted).

Comment: The book defines the convolution as $ f*g (\lambda)=\sum_{\mu+\nu=\lambda} {f (\mu) g (\nu)} $. Where $ f $ is the F valued function from above. The book does not say what g is.  I don't understand what the formal character is or the character function or anything I said above.